# Insert the contents of the tag into the get query path

Tags: javascript, html, express, get

How to get content from:

```
 <p id1="p-1-1"> Samsung Galaxy S8 Dual </ p>
```

and pass it to the param:

```
<a href="/about?param=HERE" class="btn2"> Learn more </a>
```

The contents of the p tag all change because of ajax queries and I need to transfer the contents that are currently there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call a function which takes the value of the parameter when clicked instead when the page loads.

```js
customRedirect = function(param){
  location.href = "/about?param=" + param;
}
```

```html
<p id="p-1-1"> Samsung Galaxy S8 Dual </p>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="customRedirect(document.getElementById('p-1-1').innerHTML)" class="btn2"> Learn more </a>
```

A better way to do it (in my case using jquery) :

```js
$("[customParam]").click(function(){
  location.href = "/about?param=" + $('#' + $(this).attr('call') ).html()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p-1-1"> Samsung Galaxy S8 Dual </p>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" customParam call="p-1-1" class="btn2"> Learn more </a>
```

Without jquery:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[customParam]")
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  elems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    location.href = "/about?param=" + document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('call') ).innerHTML
  })
}
```

```html
<p id="p-1-1"> Samsung Galaxy S8 Dual </p>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" customParam call="p-1-1" class="btn2"> Learn more </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value like this:

```
var v = document.querySelector('p[id1="p-1-1"]').value;
```

and set the param like this:

```
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("btn2")[0];
target.href = target.href.substring(0, target.href.indexOf("=") + 1) + '"' + v + '"';
```